# How to separate profiles between work and home in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

I thought this problem should be quite common, but still cannot find a way to solve it.

Below is how the `settings.xml` looks like in my working environment:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>...</mirrors>
    <servers>...</servers>
    <profiles>
        <id>work</id>
        <repositories>...</repositories>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>work</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

When I'm at home,

- I don't need the mirror behind vpn
- I want to use additional repositories
- I want to use different authentication methods for deployment

Is there a way to uniform these requirements into a single `settings.xml` such that I only need to switch profiles? Or, what do you suggest to make life easier?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to create a git repository in `$HOME/.m2/` which excludes `repository` and checkin your `settings.xml` file. By switching a branch you are either at home or at work...

Comment: @khmarbaise haha, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Maven profiles.
Create to profiles, one for work, on for home with the regarding settings.
See [maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles)

While you cannot directly specify every possible setting inside the profiles, you can always set properties there and use them else where in your settings.xml
I think this way you can do exactly what you asked for. If not,please provide an exact example of what is not possible with profiles.

Comment: Not what I'm asking. `Profile`s does not support all of the tags I'm using. Some of them are only usable in `settings`.

Comment: I enhanced my answer, please see above

Comment: Still, I don't see that a trivial task. Can you elaborate? As I've stated in my question, I want one repo with mirror, and corresponding authentication at work, but two repo without mirror at home.

Comment: Yes, you are right I did not see, that you asked exactly for those tags that cannot be used inside a profile, sorry for that.